# Query works fine,but SQLCommand throws 'invalid name'

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sqlclient

I've this query string, which works fine when I manually run it:

```
private const string _sold_products_query = @"SELECT rp.Id, pl.ProductName, rp.Price, rp.[StatusDate] FROM [dbo].product_name_list as pl INNER JOIN [dbo].sold_products as rp ON pl.Id = rp.FK_product_name_list;";
```

if I do this still doesn't work:

```
private const string _sold_products_query = @"SELECT rp.Id, pl.ProductName, rp.Price, rp.StatusDate FROM dbo.product_name_list as pl INNER JOIN dbo.sold_products as rp ON pl.Id = rp.FK_product_name_list;";
```

Same if put brackets everywhere like that:

```
private const string _sold_products_query = @"SELECT [rp].[Id], [pl].[ProductName], [rp].[Price], [rp].[StatusDate] FROM [dbo].[product_name_list] as pl INNER JOIN [dbo].[sold_products] as rp ON [pl].[Id] = [rp].[FK_product_name_list];";
```

But when I put it as argument in SQLCommand object and run methon ExecuteReader it throws this exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'StatusDate'.'
```

code:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(_sold_products_query, conn);
SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Query tables:

[image]

[image]

CREATE TABLE statements:

```
    CREATE TABLE [product_name_list] (
        [Id]                    int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
        [ProductName]           varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE [sold_products] (
        [Id]                    int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
        [FK_product_name_list]  int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES product_name_list(Id),
        [Price]                 decimal,
        [StatusDate]                    Date
    );
```

Connection string works fine, because another query works. Does anyone have an idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: remove the brackets

Comment: @Iria Nope, doesn't help

Comment: If this works in SSMS, then you could be pointing at the wrong (different yet similar) database you have laying around. Quite simply its telling you `StatusDate` is invalid `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @SemyonLabzov this really doesn't make sense, there is missing information or things aren't what they seem

Comment: @TheGeneral What can I show to make it clear?

Comment: @SemyonLabzov the error is crystal clear - there's no column with that name in `sold_products` whatever that is. It's not about brackets. It's impossible to answer the question without knowing the schemas of the tables or views involved. You may be trying to connect to a wrong database, or trying to use a view that doesn't have that column, or the view may be trying to read from a table that doesn't have that column. You're asking people to guess what the possible causes may be

Comment: Your connection string is either pointing to the wrong server/DB, or the user you're connecting to the DB with has different permissions.

Comment: @SemyonLabzov to make it clear you have to post a *reproducible* example - the CREATE TABLE or CREATE VIEW statements (images can't run), actual code that produces that error and the full exception text, not just a part of it. I suspect that as you try to create a reproduction script you'll find what the error is - a missing column or permission, or a wrong connection string

Comment: If you want to debug this `exec sp_columns sold_products` from your C# code. and see what columns are showing, this will point you in the right direction. Your probably connecting to the wrong database or instance as @TheGeneral already pointed out.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts I found reason. It because I have master db which by mistake I ran create statements. Thank you for this command

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts But I don't know why my connection string which I use to publish my db doesn't point to db I want to?

Comment: I'll have the imaginary points thanks :), it's hard to tell without seeing your exact string and the properties of the dbs

Comment: @TheGeneral I trying to find out how to get it from SMSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to debug this:

`exec sp_columns sold_products` from your C# code will give you all column info from the table `sold_products` if there is a difference with what you see in SSMS you are connection to a different instance or database.

Your SqlConnection or DbConnection have a property [ConnectionString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).

#### Get connection info from SSMS

At the bottom of every SSMS window is the following status bar. (Screenshot is from SSMS 18)
[image: SSMS Status Bar]

1. Is your Instance
2. Is your login name
3. Is the current connected database.

(you can also see this in the properties window in SSMS)

The Connectionstring properties should match your SSMS connection.

### Extra

In ssms you can even connect to multiple instances at once if you use the Registered Servers window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>). Connected will show X/Y. X = the number of open connections, Y being the number of attempted connections. Usefull if you need to query multiple instances at once.

[image: Multiple connections]

Answer (score -1):

it may be the [] brackets causing the issue. Try removing them or changing to the following.

```
private const string _sold_products_query = @"SELECT [rp].[Id], [pl].[ProductName], [rp].[Price], [rp].[StatusDate] FROM [dbo].[product_name]_list as pl INNER JOIN [dbo].[sold_products] as rp ON [pl].[Id] = [rp].[FK_product_name_list];";
```

generally you will use the square brackets on everything or nothing. In my view it's much better this way, rather than using square brackets on some data and not others.

Comment: "it may be the [] brackets causing the issue. " - This is just based on incorrect guess work. There is no requirement to delimit all the identifiers or none of them. It might be desirable from a code standards POV but can't cause this error